# Why does execute "as" not work in Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically, I am trying to make a system so that when a player dies a dead body (armour stand with team colour) spawns 1 Block underneath the death spot so that when it is lying on the ground the legs are hidden.

I tried to use this command in my setup:

```
/execute as (player_placeholder) run tp @e[distance=..150,type=minecraft:armor_stand,name=Corpse] ~ ~-1 ~
```

but it only teleports my armour stand to the command block and not to my friend (`player_placeholder`).

Could someone tell me why or maybe find a different solution for my plan?

Comment: If the answer doesn’t work, then it is most likely a selector issue.  What is the selector in place of `(player_placeholder)` after the execute as?

Answer (score 3):

The `as` subcommand only changes the executing entity, but the position does not change, meaning the position will still be at the previous executing entity. You need to use `at @s` to move the position to the target entity. Like this:

```
execute
  as (selector)
  at @s
run
tp @e[distance=..150,type=minecraft:armor_stand,name=Corpse] ~ ~-1 ~
```