# Minecraft checking block under entity's feet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm moving an armor stand with command blocks and I want to check if the block under it is grass.

This is what I've done so far:
`execute as @e[type=armor_stand] run execute if block ~ ~ ~ grass_block`

This doesn't seem to be working and I cant figure out why.
Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does execute "as" not work in Command Block](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/380290/why-does-execute-as-not-work-in-command-block)

Comment: You are missing "at", "as" is not enough. Moreover, `~ ~ ~` is the current block, the one under the armor stand shouldn't be `~ ~-1 ~` ?